# Different types of `decltype((const int)a)` and `decltype((const int)1)`

Tags: c++, type-conversion, decltype

```
// g++ 7.3
template<typename T>
struct td;

int main()
{
  int a = 1;

  td<decltype((const int)a)> t1;
  td<decltype((const int)1)> t2;

  return 0;
}
```

Below is the output of compilation:

error: aggregate `‘td<int> t1’` has incomplete type and cannot be defined
error: aggregate `‘td<const int> t2’` has incomplete type and cannot be defined

So, why are the types of `decltype((const int)a)` and `decltype((const int)1)` different?

Comment: Please post the compiler message in textual form instead of an image. Textual content is search friendly.

Comment: It's also accessibility-friendly.

Comment: Just in case if someone don't know: the OP is using the "type displayer" trick to display the type through compiler error message.

Comment: My experiment shows that GCC 7.3 and 8.1 behaves differently. https://godbolt.org/g/cjNLAF

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The specifiers `decltype((const int)a)` and `decltype((const int)1)` both resolve to `int`.  This is because there are no `const` prvalues of non-class type, as covered in C++17 [expr]:

> If a prvalue initially has the type `cv T`, where `T` is a cv-unqualified non-class, non-array type, the type of the expression is adjusted to `T` prior to any further analysis.

Your output might just be a bug in the diagnostic message. To confirm a compiler bug you could write some code whose behaviour differs depending on the decltype result, e.g.:

```
decltype((const int)1) x;  x = 5;
```

which should compile successfully.

Answer (score 3):

Not an answer, just additional data.

The following code,

```
template< class Type > struct T{ Type x; };

int main()
{
    int a = 1;
    T<decltype((const int)a)> t1; t1.x = 1;
    T<decltype((const int)1)> t2; t2.x = 2;
}
```

… compiles cleanly with Visual C++ 2017, but not with MinGW g++ 7.2.0:

```
[P:\temp]
> g++ foo.cpp
foo.cpp: In function 'int main()':
foo.cpp:7:31: error: use of deleted function 'T<const int>::T()'
     T<decltype((const int)1)> t2; t2.x = 2;
                               ^~
foo.cpp:1:31: note: 'T<const int>::T()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 ∩╗┐template< class Type > struct T{ Type x; };
                               ^
foo.cpp:1:31: error: uninitialized const member in 'struct T<const int>'
foo.cpp:1:39: note: 'const int T<const int>::x' should be initialized
 ∩╗┐template< class Type > struct T{ Type x; };
                                       ^
foo.cpp:7:42: error: assignment of read-only member 'T<const int>::x'
     T<decltype((const int)1)> t2; t2.x = 2;
                                          ^

[P:\temp]
> _
```

This indicates a g++ compiler bug.

Comment: Out of interest, what does MSVC do if you declare `a` as `const int a = 1;` ? I recall they do, or used to, have a "cast as lvalue" extension where casting an lvalue to the same type produced an lvalue (whereas in ISO C++ it is always a prvalue)

Comment: That also compiles cleanly.